# Send Ms Teams notification when tests fails in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

I have e2e tests which will be triggered to run at midnight. Now I want to send notification to a MS Teams channels when the test fails.

```
- task: O365PostMessageRelease@0
   inputs:
      addressType: 'url'
      url: 'https://hans.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/cfe11f3f-69ee-4447-ad1b'
      messageType: 'message'
      title: 'Test Result'
      summary: 'test result summary'
      text: 'here you can see the last test run results'
      includeLink: true
      linkText: 'View Release Detail'
```

the test results are puplished as an artifact like this

```
      - publish: junit-result.xml
        artifact: cypress_results_combined
```

Now I want to send the notification only when the test fails. How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [specify a condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions) to the `O365PostMessageRelease@0` so that it runs only when that condition is met.

> You can specify the conditions under which each stage, job, or step
> runs. By default, a job or stage runs if it does not depend on any
> other job or stage, or if all of the jobs or stages that it depends on
> have completed and succeeded. By default, a step runs if nothing in
> its job has failed yet and the step immediately preceding it has
> finished. You can customize this behavior by forcing a stage, job, or
> step to run even if a previous dependency fails or by specifying a
> custom condition.
>
> You can specify conditions under which a step, job, or stage will run.
>
> - Only when all previous dependencies with the same agent pool have
>   succeeded. If you have different agent pools, those stages or jobs
>   will run concurrently. This is the default if there is not a condition
>   set in the YAML.
> - Even if a previous dependency has failed, unless the run was canceled.
>   Use succeededOrFailed() in the YAML for this condition.
> - Even if a previous dependency has failed, even if the run was
>   canceled. Use always() in the YAML for this condition.
> - Only when a previous dependency has failed. Use failed() in the YAML
>   for this condition.
> - Custom conditions

Depending on how test execution is carried out and how a failure is handled (this part is left out of the question) there is a few options

1. Run the notification task only when the pipeline has failed by specifying `condition: failed()`.
2. Create a custom condition based on the output of the test execution step/job

There are more detials and examples in the section about [Specifying conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions) in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

If your test step doesn't return error code to pipeline(show passed), but only record test result in `junit-result.xml` file, you need to parse the xml file(eg: powershell task) and get the 'failed' test case value, set it as [variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts), evaluate the variable value in [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for the notification task.