# Find out which job and task failed in an Azure pipeline run?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am running multiple Azure pipelines, each contains a release with multiple jobs, for which there are multiple tasks.
If the pipeline fails, I would like to know, during the pipeline run, which task in which job has failed.
I have a service hook in a Microsoft Teams channel, to which I want to send notifications.
Let's say I add a task which runs only if any previous one fails, and in this task I would like to send the Teams notification about pipeline failure.
Is there a way for me, in this job/task to know where the pipeline broke up (without setting a pipeline variable value with this information, as I have over 20 pipelines (and growing) with more than 6 jobs and 100 tasks in each)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68921274/send-ms-teams-notification-when-tests-fails-in-azure-devops-pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you may try to [Create and send messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using?tabs=PowerShell#the-flow-for-sending-adaptive-cards-via-an-incoming-webhook-is-as-follows) with a custom card in Teams channel. Kindly refer to the brief steps below.

1. Add and configure Incoming Webhook connector;

[image]

2. Copy out the `Webhook Url` and define it as the value of the
   variable `$(UrlGeneratedFromIncomingWebhookConnector)` in below
   sample YAML pipeline; it uses a PowerShell task at the end of a job
   and the task will send the customized notification cards in the
   target Teams channel, on condition that the previous task(s) fails.
   [image]

```
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - main
      paths:
        include:
        - SendNotificationThroughIncomingWebhook.yml
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    jobs:
    - job: Job_0
      steps:
      - checkout: none
      - script: echo Hello, world!
        displayName: 'Job_0_Succeeded'
    - job: Job_1
      dependsOn: Job_0
      steps:
        - checkout: none
        - script: |
            Write-Host "##vso[task.logissue type=error]Something went very wrong."
            exit 1
          displayName: 'Simulate a failed task'
        - task: PowerShell@2
          displayName: 'Send Notification Through Incoming Webhook'
          condition: failed()
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              $URL = '$(UrlGeneratedFromIncomingWebhookConnector)'
              $header = @{
              'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
              }
              
              $body = @"
              {
                  "@type": "MessageCard",
                  "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
                  "themeColor": "0076D7",
                  "summary": "CI Pipeline Notification",
                  "sections": [
                      {
                          "activityTitle": "$(Build.DefinitionName) - $(Build.BuildNumber)",
                          "activitySubtitle": "status : $(Agent.JobStatus)",
                          "activityImage": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTy5ihdbdBvYPJ6cEoJFkF6ED9I7LnoaP22yg&usqp=CAU",
                          "facts": [
                              {
                                  "name": "Build",
                                  "value": "$(Build.DefinitionName) - $(Build.BuildNumber)"
                              },
                              {
                                      "name": "Job Name",
                                      "value": "$(Agent.JobName)"
                              },
                              {
                                  "name": "Repository",
                                  "value": "$(Build.Repository.Name)"
                              },
                              {
                                  "name": "Branch",
                                  "value": "$(Build.SourceBranchName)"
                              },
                              {
                                  "name": "Commit",
                                  "value": "$(Build.SourceVersionMessage)"
                              },
                              {
                                  "name": "Requested For:",
                                  "value": "$(Build.RequestedFor)"
                              },
                              {
                                  "name": "Date & Time:",
                                  "value": "$(system.pipelineStartTime)"
                              }
                          ],
                          "markdown": true
                      }
                  ],
                  "potentialAction": [
                      {
                          "@type": "OpenUri",
                          "name": "View Pipeline Run",
                          "targets": [
                              {
                                  "os": "default",
                                  "uri": "$(System.CollectionUri)/$(System.TeamProject)/_build/results?buildId=$(Build.BuildId)&view=results"
                              }
                          ]
                      },
                      {
                          "@type": "OpenUri",
                          "name": "View Commit",
                          "targets": [
                              {
                                  "os": "default",
                                  "uri": "$(System.CollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_git/$(Build.Repository.Name)/commit/$(Build.SourceVersion)?refName=refs%2Fheads%2F$(Build.SourceBranchName)"
                              }
                          ]
                      }
                  ]
              }
              "@ 
              Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $URL -Headers $header -Body $body | ConvertTo-Json
```

3. The pipeline will simulate a failed task and send the message like
   below in your Teams channel;
   [image]
4. For more information, please refer to the following documents;
   [Create an Incoming Webhook - Teams | Microsoft
   Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook)
   [Create and send messages - Teams | Microsoft
   Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using?tabs=PowerShell#the-flow-for-sending-adaptive-cards-via-an-incoming-webhook-is-as-follows)