# Azure Devops Pipeline Teams Integration: changing channel and setting up pipeline monitoring

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, microsoft-teams

I'm currently trying to figure out, how to send alerts for failed release pipeline to a specific MS Teams channel. I followed the following link and set up Azure Pipelines App in one of my MS Teams team: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/integrations/microsoft-teams?view=azure-devops

Nevertheless I could only select the genereal channel like myTeam > General but I want to move the bot to another monitoring channel (monitoring devops) inside of 'myTeam'.

It's unclear to me if the bot is automatically in all channels and I can just enter: `@azure pipelines subscribe [pipeline url]` into my monitoring channel or do I have to set it up differently? Since I'm in a productive environment, I'm not able to just test it. Therefore would like to clarify first before executing.

Further, I have clicked on the app in the general channel and opened it, set it up with my devops project but it doesn't show any pipelines. Do I lack permission or do I have to set it up in teams using the commands like `@azure pipelines subscribe` first?

Comment: Actually you can test it. Just create a new project, new repository or a new organization. Or register a personal account and create an organization, its free up to 5 users. Create one release pipeline with one powershell script: "throw" thats it. You can test it easily in your own environment.

Comment: This one could be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/teams?view=azure-devops | This one too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68921274/send-ms-teams-notification-when-tests-fails-in-azure-devops-pipeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To monitor the target release in specific channel， please follow below steps:

1. Your `teams account` should be `Project Administrator` in target project as per the [Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/integrations/microsoft-teams?view=azure-devops#prerequisites).

[image]

2. When you setup, you can type the existing target channel so that it's not general.

[image]

3. The release url you can get from devops release page:

[image]

Go to target team/channel, run command `@azure pipelines subscribe https://dev.azure.com/myorg/myproject/_release?definitionId=123&view=mine&_a=releases.` to monitor on target release(change the release info to yours).

[image]

It will monitor on `release start`, `Release deployment approval pending`, `Release deployment completed` event. If you would like to change the monitoring event, you can type `@Azure Pipelines subscriptions` in channel -> View all subscriptions -> remove or add new event.

[image]

You can only keep `Release deployment completed event` if you only would like to check the release result.

[image]

> Further, I have clicked on the app in the general channel and opened it, set it up with my devops project but it doesn't show any pipelines. Do I lack permission or do I have to set it up in teams using the commands like @azure pipelines subscribe first?

Yes, your teams account should meet Prerequisites listed above, and you need to use `@azure pipelines subscribe` command in channel to tell teams which pipeline is monitoring.

Comment: Thanks, my problem was that I had to enter the channel manually from MS Teams team. If I chose a team, it has been automatically using the general channel.